# UIPageViewController with button on each page, which presents a detailed view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have set up a collection view that presents different view controllers on cell click in a container below the collection view. These different view controllers are consisted of page views that present different number of products from the same category which is selected in the collection view.
I want to add a button to the pages such that every page should present detailed information about that product (ex. popping in another view controller) on touch up inside. I can't come up with anything by now and I'll be really grateful if somebody shows me how to do that.
Thanks in advance.

This is the collection view, which cells are presented in the container.

[image]

This is the view controller that is presented in the container.

[image]

Here is the code for my first product page view:

```
var pageViewController: UIPageViewController!
var pageTitles:NSArray!
var pageImages:NSArray!
var productTitle:NSArray!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.pageTitles = NSArray(objects: "За още по-ефективна подкрепа на вените.", "Живей с лекота без разширени вени.", "За ефективна подкрепа на вените.", "Единствените в България кърпички против хемороиди.")

    self.pageImages = NSArray(objects: "RuvenorForte.jpg", "RuvenorGel.jpg", "RuvenorKapsuli.jpg", "RuvenorKurpi.jpg", "ProbienFemiFlora.jpg")

    self.productTitle = NSArray(objects: "Рувенор Форте", "Рувенор гел", "Рувенор капсули","Рувенор кърпи")

    self.pageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageViewController") as! UIPageViewController

    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self

    let startVC = self.viewControllerAtIndex(0) as ContentViewController
    let viewControllers = NSArray(object: startVC)

    self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers as? [UIViewController], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

    //self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 62, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 60)
    let height = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height
    if height == 568 {
        self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 66)        }
    else if  height == 667{
        self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 66)

    }
    else {
        self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 230)        }

    self.addChildViewController(self.pageViewController)
    self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController.view)
    self.pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)


}


override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent    }

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func viewControllerAtIndex(index: Int) -> ContentViewController
{
    if ((self.pageTitles.count == 0) || (index >= self.pageTitles.count)) {
        return ContentViewController()
    }

    let vc: ContentViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ContentViewController") as! ContentViewController

    vc.imageFile = self.pageImages[index] as! String
    vc.titleText = self.pageTitles[index] as! String
    vc.product = self.productTitle[index] as! String
    vc.pageIndex = index


    return vc


}


// MARK: - Page View Controller Data Source

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
{

    let vc = viewController as! ContentViewController
    var index = vc.pageIndex as Int


    if (index == 0 || index == NSNotFound)
    {
        return nil

    }

    index--
    return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index)

}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    let vc = viewController as! ContentViewController
    var index = vc.pageIndex as Int

    if (index == NSNotFound)
    {
        return nil
    }

    index++

    if (index == self.pageTitles.count)
    {
        return nil
    }

    return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index)

}

func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int
{
    return self.pageTitles.count
}

func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int
{
    return 0
}}
```

And this is the code from the view controller to whom I pass all the information:

class ContentViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var lightPurpleView: UIView!

@IBOutlet var productTitle: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var infoLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!

@IBOutlet var infoTextField: UITextView!

@IBOutlet var infoTextField1: UITextView!

@IBOutlet var infoTextField2: UITextView!

var pageIndex: Int!
var titleText: String!
var imageFile: String!
var infoButton: UIButton!
var product: String!
var listovka: String!
var listovka1: String!
var listovka2: String!  



override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let upSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleSwipes:"))

    upSwipe.direction = .Up
    view.addGestureRecognizer(upSwipe)
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(upSwipe)

    self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: self.imageFile)

    self.titleLabel.text = self.titleText

    self.infoTextField.text = self.listovka
    self.infoTextField1.text = self.listovka1
    self.infoTextField2.text = self.listovka2

    self.productTitle.text = self.product
    self.lightPurpleView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    self.infoLabel.text = "Листовка"
    scrollView.contentSize.height = 3375
    scrollView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    self.infoTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    self.infoTextField.clipsToBounds = true

    self.infoTextField1.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    self.infoTextField1.clipsToBounds = true
    self.infoTextField2.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    self.infoTextField2.clipsToBounds = true

    self.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false





    lightPurpleView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor().CGColor
    lightPurpleView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2.0, height: 2.0)
    lightPurpleView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    lightPurpleView.layer.shadowRadius = 2
    lightPurpleView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    lightPurpleView.clipsToBounds = false

    imageView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor().CGColor
    imageView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2.0, height: 2.0)
    imageView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    imageView.layer.shadowRadius = 2
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    imageView.clipsToBounds = false


}}
```

So basically I want to add this button, which is on the second picture and instead of scrolling down to see the textViews, just to present them in another view controller (dependent on the indexPath of the page view for that product category) that pops up.

Comment: what code / layout do you have in place so far? sounds pretty straight-forward to add a button!?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I made an edit. Hope it clears a bit what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: the first thing I see is that you create and add a pageViewController "by hand", let the interface builder do that work for you, you can set up the data source and stuff like that there as well. In particular, don't set frame properties, let autolayout do the layout.

Comment: Thanks but even if I recreate the page view controller how can I add this button and make it work in the correct way.